# Adding data at runtime into dataframes using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers

I am trying to create an empty MXD to act as a template.

I will have three dataframes for maps, each holding a different object from ArcSDE (1 raster object and 2 features).

I know how to query all of the data frames, but I am having trouble finding out how to add data to the dataframes.

Is there an online guide anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section on [ArcPy in the ArcGIS help documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_is_ArcPy/000v000000v7000000/).

In the mapping module, you'll find a function for [listing the data frames](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ListDataFrames/00s30000001p000000/) and [adding a layer to the data frame](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/AddLayer/00s300000025000000/).

The documentation has examples of exactly what you are describing.